# Capture a UIImage without dismissing the UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, camera-overlay

I have used a custom overlay view over a `UIImagePickerController` to capture a `UIImage`.

The custom overlay view has one button. On the click of this button I want to capture the `UIImage` without closing the `UIImagePickerController`?
How do I get a `UIImage` without using the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate method. Just don't dismiss the image picker in the delegate method and the image picker will stay in view.

Answer (score 1):

I think `picker.takePicture()` might do what you want...From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImagePickerController/takePicture):

> Use this method in conjunction with a custom overlay view to initiate
>   the programmatic capture of a still image. **This supports taking more
>   than one picture without leaving the interface, but requires that you
>   hide the default image picker controls.**